# Excel: How to lookup a value that has multiple search criterias?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm looking to implement a formula that would return the total quantity attributed to a certain ID. I was relying on a classic IfError and Vlookup combo to get the data, but I have many suppliers that use the same vendor code (supposedly unique ID) for different branches working on different commodities (which act as separate entities from a logistics perspective).

I have to manually split up the quantity attributed to certain suppliers by looking for the logistics agent responsible for them, and when the same log agent handles multiple commodities for the same supplier, I manually dig for the material codes.

I would like to know how to synthesize the manual process I undertake in a single formula.

I was using this formula to get the data in a pivot table `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2),Pivot!$A$4:$B$105,2,0),0)`

And I need to incorporate three search criteria to get the qty of a specific supplier's sub-entities (Vendor ID, name of Log Agent, Material ID).

[Part of pivot table where I'd get data pasted as value ][1]

[Example of how the data is stored and result I get with Vlookup function][2]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1v0f.png
>
> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmFi3.png

Answer (score 0):

With the following solution, you will need to fill all the cells with vendor id and PURCH_GRP_NAME. If the range is built from a pivot table, there is an option to "repeat" the identical values on every row.

Once this is done, you can use a formula like this (the XXXXXX is the search criterion. I did not understand where this is supposed to come from):

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$105,MATCH(XXXXXX,$A$1:$A$105&$B$1:$B$105&$C$1:$C$105,0))
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to turn it into a matrix formula.